# Dagger Hilt. Runtime error. Error: ViewModel has no zero argument constructor (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I get an error (MainViewModel has no zero argument constructor).
It seems to me that mistake is in misusing Hilt, but I can't find. There are similar questions on SA, but they don't fit my case.
I can't find where did I go wrong and will be gratifeul for any help.

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class mypackage.main.MainViewModel
  /* bla bla bla */
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<mypackage.main.MainViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
 at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
 ... 39 more
```

ViewModel begins like that:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: MainRepository,
    private val dispatchers: DispatcherProvider
) : ViewModel() {
 
    // body
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
// etc
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCurrencyApi() : CurrencyApi = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(CurrencyApi::class.java)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMainRepository(api: CurrencyApi): MainRepository = DefaultMainRepository(api)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDispatchers(): // blablabla
    }
}
```

MainRepository:

```
interface MainRepository {
    suspend fun getRates(base: String) : Resource<CurrencyResponse>
    }
```

DefaultMainRepository

```
class DefaultMainRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: CurrencyApi
) : MainRepository {

    override suspend fun getRates(base: String): Resource<CurrencyResponse> {
        return try {
            val response = api.getRates(base)
            val result = response.body()
            if (response.isSuccessful && result != null) {
                Resource.Success(result)
            } else {
                Resource.Error(response.message())
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Resource.Error(e.message ?: "An error occurred")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `@Inject constructor` both from your `MainViewModel` and `DefaultMainRepository`. You don't need this since you are already providing those from dagger module

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it results in the same error

Comment: Please also provides `MainViewModel ` using dagger module when you removing `@Inject constructor`

Comment: you can't pass the interface directly as constructor , must to bind it

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by changing Dagger Hilt dependencies versions to earlier. I think there was mismatch in those versions. The rest of the code turned out to be correct, it seems..

Comment: Which version did you end up using? I am using 2.28.3-alpha for dagger-hilt and 1.0.0-alpha03 for andreoidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel and hilt-compiler and it is failing the same way as yours...

Comment: Adding to my last comment, I upgraded to 2.3.7 and removed the dependencies for androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel and hilt-compiler since they are no longer needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I use older: implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02" But I think that when I used newest versions I just did something incorrectly with them, maybe there was some mismatch of them.